# Connect to Pythons SOAPpy server with Perls SOAP::Lite

Tags: python, perl, soap, soappy, soaplite

I'm completely blocked on this one and I require your assistance.

I developed a SOAP server using Python and Soappy library. It works pretty well if I use another Python application as the client, however ones I try to connect with Perls SOAP::Lite application it doesn't work anymore.

This is what I get from Perl script.

```
500 Internal Server Error at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3427
```

And here's the error message from the server ones Perl is trying to connect.

```
*** Internal exception 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_name' ******
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/Server.py", line 232, in do_POST
    method = r._name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_name'
```

Of course I looked up the sources and was unable to find any conclusion.

I'm completely new to Perl, but same application connected to another web service I developped (using gSOAP in C++) work's fine.

I did some research on google and I found this:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/200504.mbox/%3CJPEHKJKAFLKINKCFJHMBMELACNAA.i.venuti@caribel.pisa.it%3E

However I didn't manage an explonation simple enough on different kinds of WSDLs and influence it has on the application.

I will provide sources if they will be requested, however I don't think that is necessarily since I used basic example. What looks usefull is my namespace defined by Python and how I access it in Perl.

Python server:

```
server.registerObject(Memorizer(), "urn://memorizer")
```

And here's the Perl definition:

```
use SOAP::Lite +autodispatch =>
        uri => 'urn://memorizer',
        proxy => 'http://localhost:8081';
```

All choices on variables, adresses etc are complitely arbitrairy but consistent. I hope someone will have an idea how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote; I would question soap usefulness when used without WSDL.

Comment: Of course, other application provide WSDL file to Perl's script and works fine. Unfortunately there is no such possibility for soappy (or am I wrong?). Thanks for quick answer.